# How to re-hide a button when a user deleted a letter from a specified word in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got here a script that will show a hidden button when a user typed a specific word, in this scenario: "Criminal Law" or "Criminal Law2".

Once the user typed any of these words, a button will show up.

However, a problem I couldn't figure out is how to hide this button again when a user deleted the typed words or if an entry no longer matches the specified word. So if there's only "Criminal La" left, it shouldn't show the button anymore.

Please see my code:

```js
$('#crimlaw1').on('keyup', function() {
});
$("#textarea3").on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val().indexOf("Criminal Law") > -1){
        $('#crimlaw1').css('display','block');

    }
});

$('#crimlaw2').on('keyup', function() {
});
$("#textarea3").on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val().indexOf("Criminal Law2") > -1){
        $('#crimlaw2').css('display','block');

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4"></textarea>

<button id="crimlaw1" id="crimlaw1" style="display:none">Crim</button>

<button id="crimlaw2" id="crimlaw1" style="display:none">Crim 2</button>
```

I would appreciate any help on this specific problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can control lenght your text whic is in the text area if the lenght decrease you can hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 id's per one button, that is invalid.

Also you don't need 4 key-up events. You just need one and do your logic inside.

```js
$("#textarea3").on('keyup', function() {

  if ($(this).val().indexOf("Criminal Law") === 0) {
    $('#crimlaw1').css('display', 'block');
  }else {
    $('#crimlaw1').css('display', 'none');
  }
  
  
  if ($(this).val().indexOf("Criminal Law2") === 0) {
    $('#crimlaw1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#crimlaw2').css('display', 'block');
  }else {
    $('#crimlaw2').css('display', 'none');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4"></textarea>

<button id="crimlaw1" style="display:none">Crim</button>

<button id="crimlaw2" style="display:none">Crim 2</button>
```

Comment: Although I encountered another problem when adding another block. Please teach me how to add another rule for a lot more buttons? I'm really a beginner in coding, but I need this code to work for a simple tool we are using.

Comment: @ixcode You should take a bit more time then and study the code i wrote, Its pretty strait forward. And you haven't said what problem you  have encountered nether do I see the code you are trying to add. I don't see how can I help you more then this. this is very simple jquery here we are talking about. Learn if else javascript statements https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#textarea3").on('change keyup', function() {

    $('#crimlaw1').css('display','none');  // Keep btn hidden without need for else statement

    // use equal operator for string matching instead of indexOf 
    if( $(this).val() === 'Criminal Law' ){
        $('#crimlaw1').css('display','block');
    }
});

// Same for second condition.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea3" spellcheck="true" rows="4"></textarea>

<button id="crimlaw1" style="display:none">Crim</button>

<button id="crimlaw2" style="display:none">Crim 2</button>
```

Comment: Hi can you please tell me why if I add any text or a single space before a word, it wouldn't detect it?

Comment: Because equal (===) operator matches the exact string, in your previous case indexOf() function checks for matching of substring, so if you need exact match then first case if need to check substring than second case.

Comment: Thank you, I've tweaked it a little bit and is working fine now.